# How to import icdiff in python. Is there any other python module like icdiff which gives colored difference?

Tags: python

I have installed icdiff using "pip install icdiff", But when I am importing it in my code it is giving

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<pyshell#509>", line 1, in <module>
  import icdiff
  ImportError: No module named icdiff
```

but I am able to run it as a command from shell " icdiff textfile1 textfile2"

How to import this module, or is there some other text comparison module which gives colored output??

Comment: Really? There is no `icdiff` in PyPI. How did you install it? Do you have a local or other repository?

Comment: I installed it using pip install, but looks like its just a binary, I am not able to import it.

Comment: You can't have installed with pip using the standard repository because there is no package there. You might have downloaded it and run `python setup.py install`. Anyway, have you read any of the answers provided? Yes, it is intended to be a utility script, like a binary. But you can import the file if you link/copy the file with a `.py` extension.

Answer (score 0):

`Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement icdiff`

pip install icdiff is not working for me, are you sure you installed the module that way?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, `icdiff` is just a binary and is not intended to be used and imported as a python module:

https://github.com/jeffkaufman/icdiff

Answer (score 0):

You can clone from github:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/jeffkaufman/icdiff.git
```

Then you can sym link `icdiff.py` to the `icdiff` file:

```
$ cd icdiff
$ ln -s icdiff icdiff.py
```

Alternatively you can make a copy of `icdiff`.

Now you can import in Python using `import icdiff`.

This is not a Python package, but you can make it one by creating an empty `__init__.py` file in the `icdiff` directory:

```
$ >__init__.py
$ cd ..
$ python
>>> from icdiff import icdiff
>>> dir(icdiff)
['ConsoleDiff', 'MultipleOption', 'Option', 'OptionParser', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__version__', 'codec_print', 'codecs', 'color_codes', 'diff_files', 'diff_recursively', 'difflib', 'errno', 'filecmp', 'os', 're', 'read_file', 'replace_all', 'simple_colorize', 'start', 'sys', 'unicodedata']
```

Or you could add to the top of the `__init__.py` file:

```
from icdiff import *
```

Now in Python you can import like this:

```
>>> import icdiff
>>> dir(icdiff)
['ConsoleDiff', 'MultipleOption', 'Option', 'OptionParser', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', 'codec_print', 'codecs', 'color_codes', 'diff_files', 'diff_recursively', 'difflib', 'errno', 'filecmp', 'icdiff', 'os', 're', 'read_file', 'replace_all', 'simple_colorize', 'start', 'sys', 'unicodedata']
```